# Cisco 800 Series ARPing's to ISP are Intermittant

Tags: cisco, ping

According to my ISP, our occasional internet outages are do to a router configuration problem. They say the router must ARPing the ISP regularly. Failure to do so in 4 hours results in outgoing and incoming internet loss. According to their logs the ARPing is occurring randomly. And on some occasions, more than 4 hours apart.

The router is Cisco 800 Series.

How do I configure the ARPing to occur more frequently?

Comment: The term you're probably looking for is 'arping'.

Comment: That sounds like an ISP problem, not a router configuration problem.

Comment: "_How do I configure the ARPing to occur more frequently?_ That is not a router funtion, it is a utility that you can get for some host OSes.

Comment: @RonMaupin  ISP confirmed "ARPing". Then rep went on to say that any activity on the router at all, incoming or outgoing traffic would keep the connection alive. However, we had thousands of connections per hour for the 4 hours leading up to the drop.  I think ISP is dodging their own problem. I have escalated it.

Comment: The ISP rep doesn't know what he's talking about.  Even if you had no activity for more than  four hours, the next activity would generate an ARP request (and reply).

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [Monitoring and Maintaining ARP Information Documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_4t/ip_addr/configuration/guide/htarpmon.html) was helpful to understand ARP, ARPing and ARP Caching.

> ARP was developed to enable communications on an internetwork...Routers and Layer 3 switches need ARP to map IP addresses to MAC hardware addresses so that IP packets can be sent across networks.
>
> ...To minimize broadcasts and limit wasteful use of network resources, ARP caching was implemented....the ARP subsystem refreshes dynamic ARP entries periodically (as configured or every four hours by default) so that the ARP table reflects any changed, aged-out, or removed dynamic routes.

I ran `show ip arp` to see a list of ARPs cached, aged time and Interface name. I then ran `show intefaces` and confirmed that the ARP Timeout is at the default of 4 hours.

However according to my ISP the ARPings or ARP refresh requests are being received by them at varying times. Usually just under 4 hours but occasionally just over 4 hours (when the connection is dropped). For the last two connection drops, time between pings was 4:10 and 4:15.

I read on a [Cisco Community Post: ARP cache timeout on Cisco routers](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/arp-cache-timeout-on-cisco-routers/td-p/1868410):

> Richard Burts "the request to refresh the arp entry is generated near
> the end of the arp lifetime...Cisco adds a variable amount of time in determining when to generate the arp request. The logic is that they want to avoid synchronization of the arp entries. If we have flushed all the entries in the table and re-learned all the entries at approximately the same time then when they are about to expire we do not want to flush them all at the same time
>
> paul driver's testing revealed what Richard Burts further described:
> "while the arp timeout was set to one hour the requests to refresh the entries were all longer than an hour. So the variability that Cisco adds can be longer than the time...the bottom line is that the arp timeout is not a precise timer but an approximation of when the entries will be refreshed or be purged from the table."

It seams the best solution at this point is to reduce the ARP Timeout on my router.

```
cisco(config-if)#int f0/0
cisco(config-if)#arp timeout 10800
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what "RPing" is supposed to refer to. That's no standard procedure.

You'll need to ask your ISP what they mean.